# Batch FOR Command Not Returning Expected Path

Tags: batch-file

The `FOR` command in Windows has some options that it did not have in DOS. Specifically, it supports returning filename segments as follows.

```
  In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been enhanced.
  You can now use the following optional syntax:

  %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
  %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
  %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
  %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
  %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
  %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
  %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
  %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
  %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
  %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
```

When I try to use the following command, it does not work. Instead of printing `\Program Files`, it prints `\`.

```
  for %i in ("%programfiles%") do echo %~pi
```

It seems that only the `p` argument is incorrect because the other arguments return the expected results.

```
  > for %i in ("%programfiles%") do echo %i
  C:\Program Files

  > for %i in ("%programfiles%") do echo %~i
  C:\Program Files

  > for %i in ("%programfiles%") do echo %~fi
  C:\Program Files

  > for %i in ("%programfiles%") do echo %~is
  C:\PROGRA~1

  > for %i in ("%programfiles%") do echo %~id
  C:
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem, this is the correct and expected result. `~p` extracts the path part of a given filespec.

In this case

- `c:` is the drive, returned by `%~di`;
- `\` is the path, returned by `%~pi`;
- `Program Files` is the name, returned by `%~ni`;
- and `C:\Program Files` is the complete expanded filespec, returned by `%~fi`, or by `%~dpnxi`.

Comment: Doh! I guess it makes sense since it has no way of differentiating a filename from a folder name, so it thinks *Program Files* is a filename. **Thanks for the clarification.** For the record, using `for %i in ("%programfiles%\") do echo %~pi ` returns `\Program Files\ ` so I guess there’s that (though it’s not *quite* what I wanted).

Answer (score 0):

`%~pI        - expands %I to a path only`

But it assumes the %I is a path+filename, so it removes the last component.

I tested it with a file `C:\temp\two\myFile.txt`

**for %%I in ("c:\temp\two\myFile.txt") do echo %~pI**
shows `\temp\two\`

But for only the path
**for %%I in ("c:\temp\two") do echo %~pI**
it shows only `\temp\'

But if there is a \ at the end
**for %%I in ("c:\temp\two") do echo %~pI**
it shows again `\temp\two\`